Having trouble with a 555 Astable timer outputting into NPN transistor switch that controls 741 Op-Amp
I have been building a circuit that takes the output of a 555 IC and outputs it into an NPN transistor that acts as a switch to toggle a 741 Op-Amp connected to an 8 ohm, 0.5 watt speaker.
I'm new to the concepts of negative voltage and transistor functions, so it would be much appreciated if you could help teach me if I did something wrong. I designed this schematic and would like to know if it is correct and will successfully amplify the output waveform of the 555 timer and push it through the speaker.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Edit: I have updated the schematic based on multiple points of feedback. I have also taken some liberties in designing around issues mentioned with my previous design. Which issues, if any, are still present within my design, after these changes?

simulate this circuit
These are the most recent updated graphs for the schematic:


(along with this, I'd like to apologize as I have not been able to work on this question as frequently as I'd like to, a large storm came through and demolished much of my town, and it has greatly hindered my schedule)

A 741 can't drive 8 Ω. I would think that something like 1 kΩ would be the minimum load. Relevant: reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp.

It's unclear what exactly you want this circuit to do. The transistor is definitely not connected properly, or there's some missing elements. The resistances and capacitance you're using for the 555 are also impractical.

I've cleaned up the schematic a bit to make it easier to read. There are several problems with it, Control is not usually connected directly to ground, it usually has a capacitor, something like 0.01uF, to ground. 10Ω resistors are very low values for a 555 circuit. Not sure what the transistor and opamp are even meant to do, you could probably drive the speaker better directly from the 555 than the way it is.

@Hearth I would want the circuit to constantly generate a tone, and have it play loudly through the speaker. The transistor was intended to act as a "switch" of sorts, that controlled the 741. I will also add, I am still not fully aware as to how these components work, and am studying more about them as a whole.

@Transistor Could you help explain to me why a 741 cannot drive the speaker? Also I much appreciate the attached question, I will definitely keep it for future reference!

The 741's (and most other small signal op-amps') output transistors are too small. A very crude calculation from Ohm's Law, I = V/R shows that with a 5 V supply and 8 Ω load you'd get I = 5 / 8 = 600 mA. The 741 can only deliver about 20 mA max.

@RetroBoltDev Your circuit will not do anything close to what you want it to do.

@Transistor I see now, so if I wanted to connect it to a speaker, I'd somehow have to either use an op-amp that could support that amount of current, or find another option to obtain the right amount of power to run the speaker at the same frequency? Would simply adding a resistor to the output of the op-amp, such as the 1k ohm you suggested, work in this case? (Edit: I apologize as well for my tardiness in replying, studying for finals has me very crunched for time but I still very much want to learn electrical engineering)

@Hearth Okay, how would I go about starting to figure out a way to get the circuit to function how I'd like it to?

@RetroBoltDev I'd start by learning more about how op amps and BJTs work; it seems you're missing some fundamentals on both. Consider using a piezo buzzer instead of an 8 Ω speaker; they don't require as much drive current.

@Hearth I see, I certainly am learning more about electrical engineering as a whole, but I will absolutely research more about bipolar junction transistors and op-amps work. Do you have any recommendations on where to go for more information?

@RetroBoltDev The book The Art of Electronics by Horowitz and Hill is a pretty good introduction.

What is the point of R4, R5, R3, and V2 in your updated design?

Changes required:

R1 & R2: increase from 10ohm to 1k.
R3: reduce from 100k to 10k.
C1: reduce from 100uF to 1uF.  And please don't draw schematic wires through components.
Remove Q1, which will leave 3 wire-ends dangling; simply connect all these dangling wire-ends together.
Replace 8-ohm speaker with 10k resistor.
Connect a scope probe at the op-amp output

After doing all these changes, you should now have an oscillator that produces a square-ish waveform in the audible range, which you can see on a scope screen.
If you want to drive a speaker with this, then you will need to add a buffer stage between the op-amp output & the speaker, one that can supply enough current to the speaker.  I can help with that later.

UPDATE 2024-05-25
The OP has changed the circuit.  Here are the changes required to get a working circuit, from which you can then work out what is going on.  I suspect the simulator you are using may not be correctly simulating the 555 timer in regards to its output stage (pin marked "output"), so I suggest making these changes first, then doing further investigation.

To list the changes:

Remove R5, or make its value very large, say, 1 MEG-Ω.
Change R3 from 100Ω to 100kΩ.
Move the GND symbol from the join of V1 & V2, to the bottom of V2 (the negative pin of V2).

After doing these changes, the output voltage at U1."output" should be close to a square-wave that switches from 0V to about 9 or 10V wrt GND, at some frequency in the audio range.
Then the next steps are:

Adjust the circuit to give the frequency and duty-cycle you want.
Investigate how to couple this to an amplifier to drive a speaker.


Ah, thank you very much for the changes. If I may ask, can you help me understand how these changes are crucial and what they impact? Also, I'm new to circuit design so I definitely will not draw wires through circuit parts anymore, thank you for that feedback.

May I suggest making these changes, then simulating the circuit, and trying to understand what these changes affect, any why they are important.   After trying this yourself, feel free to ask more questions.  After that, we can discuss driving a speaker.

I edited the schematic, and believe I have gotten closer to what you're describing, has my design fixed any major flaws?

Looking at the last schematic you posted: Suggest remove the op-amp completely for now.  Change R9 to 10k, delete R8 (replace with a wire), and connect R6 to U1 output pin.  Then run your simulation, look at U1 output pin with a scope.  Post your results.  Good luck.4

Running a 741 on 10V is 50% below its specifications, so you were getting poor performance because of that too. A 741 needs a minimum of 20V supply (whether ±10V or 0V..20V).
A 555 has a push-pull driver stage that can drive a speaker much better than the 741’s output stage. That 741 is making things worse, not better, especially with a 10V supply.
Connect 555’s output via 100μF directly to one end of the speaker. It should be reasonably loud. R1, R2, C1, and C3 on your revised schematic are good. Just no point to the 741.
General-purpose operational amplifiers don’t drive heavy loads. They do operations on voltages, but to drive anything less than a couple kΩ, there needs to be a buffer stage that can supply the current needed by the load as the op-amp can’t do that.
If you wanted to drive a speaker louder than a 555 can, use an LM386. The whole circuit will then work well from a single 5V supply, and the speaker output will get louder as the supply voltage goes up. The 555 output’s amplitude is too high for an LM386 so it’ll need to be divided down using a resistive divider first to match LM386’s input voltage range.

I see, I will definitely try revising the diagram with either the standalone 555 or the added LM386, do you have somewhere I could get information such as input voltages and such?

It’s in the datasheet and I’m sure there are application notes (app notes) for LM386
